# How to get Location coordinates when app in background mode at the same time suspend mode

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I used **loc_manager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()** but didUpdateLocations not calling in foreground ,background and suspend mode can anyone help me please,

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
    loc_manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    loc_manager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
    loc_manager.delegate = self
    loc_manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    loc_manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
    loc_manager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Location in foreground** 
In the foreground the CLLocationManager object and delegates will do fine. This will also work with the 'while in use' location permission.

**For Location in background**
Please enable the Background Modes from the capabilities of the project and enable the 'Location updates'. After enabling this, the only configuration to get the updates in the background(not in killed state) is to set'allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates' to true(which you have done already).

For more information on getting location in the background follow :

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620568-allowsbackgroundlocationupdates

**For location in application suspended or killed**
Here the significant location changes are only needed when you want to get the location when the application is killed by the user(or Suspended). This significant location change will launch the application in background and read the location of the device. This mode needs 'Always authorised' location permission.

For significant location changes while the application is in killed state, follow below link. This is in objective C but it can be easily done in swift also.

http://mobileoop.com/getting-location-updates-for-ios-7-and-8-when-the-app-is-killedterminatedsuspended

Hope this helps.